# How to connect to a JMS 1.0.2 compliant queue in Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, jms

I'm updating some code that uses org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer102 to connect to an IBM MQ instance. The queue in question supports JMS 1.0.2 but not later versions.

Has it been decided with Spring 4 that queues like this no longer exist? Should I retrieve the org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer102 code from previous Spring releases to use it or is there a new and better Spring 4 way?

Cheers,
Pete

Comment: I don't see any version restrictions on org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer, did you already try this class?

Comment: In truth I haven't tried connecting with the non 102 version. I'm basing my thoughts on the fact that http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer102.html exists at all as proof that it is required. I'll get a chance to try connecting to a queue in a few days so I'll guess I'll know for sure then. My hopes are low though.